# How to apply interp1d to each element of a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let say, I have a interpolation function.

```
def mymap():
    x = np.arange(256)
    y = np.random.rand(x.size)*255.0
    return interp1d(x, y)
```

This guy maps a number in [0,255] to a number following the profile given by `x` and `y` (now `y` is random, though). When I do following, each value in image gets mapped nicely.

```
x = imread('...')
x_ = mymap()(x)
```

However, how can I do this in Tensorflow? I want to do something like

```
img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [64, 64, 1], name="img")
distorted_image = tf.map_fn(mymap(), img)
```

But it results in an error saying

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

For information, I checked if a function map is simple as below, it works well

```
mymap2 = lambda x: x+10
distorted_image = tf.map_fn(mymap2, img)
```

How can I map each number in a tensor? Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function input of `tf.map_fn` needs to be a function written with Tensorflow ops. For instance, this one will work:

```
def this_will_work(x):
    return tf.square(x)

img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [64, 64, 1])
res = tf.map_fn(this_will_work, img)
```

---

This one will not work:

```
def this_will_not_work(x):
    return np.sinh(x)

img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [64, 64, 1])
res = tf.map_fn(this_will_not_work, img)
```

Because `np.sinh` **cannot be applied** to a TensorFlow tensor (`np.sinh(tf.constant(1))` returns an error).

---

#### Solutions

You can write your interpolation function in TensorFlow, and maybe ask for help in another StackOverflow question.

If you absolutely want to use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html), you will need to keep the code encapsulated in python. For that, you can use [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html), and use your scipy
 function inside.